# pspell returns question marks(�)

Tags: php, ubuntu, aspell, pspell

I've tried to install pspell on an Ubuntu trusty distribution with the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install libpspell-dev
sudo apt-get install php5-pspell
sudo apt-get install aspell-he`

The process seems to have succeeded since there was no error returned during the installation process.

However, when I try this in action, I get an array of question marks(�):

```
pspell_config_create("he");
$t = pspell_new('he');

$suggestions = pspell_suggest($t, 'דבל');


return view('master', compact('suggestions')); 
// the above line can be swapped with"
// print_r($suggestions);
// and the result stays the same
```

The reason I used view is that because I thought that maybe the webpage need some charset set to it so I used HTML5 document structure to achieve that, however the result remained the same.

My HTML markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="he">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    סתם טקסט לבדיקה
    <?php print_r($suggestions); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result returned from that:

`סתם טקסט לבדיקה Array ( [0] => � [1] => � [2] => � [3] => � [4] => � [5] => � [6] => � )`

I've also ran another test where I tried to do:

```
return pspell_check($t, 'הגדא') ? 'there is' : 'nope';
```

And for some reason, for any given word it returned with "nope" which means that `pspell_check` returned `false`

Any idea how to fix this?

## Edit:

When trying to retrieve the length of the results:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="he">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
@foreach($suggestions as $suggestion)
    {{ strlen($suggestion) }} <br>
@endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1
```

Which means that maybe the returned results from `pspell_suggest` method had problem retrieving the data from the aspell dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every word check returned with the same results it got me suspected that maybe the value that is being passed to the `pspell_suggest` function is corrupted.

What I did was simply tell `pspell` to use UTF-8:

```
$t = pspell_new('he', "", "", "utf-8");
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like encoding issue. You should be using `UTF-8` for the HTML content (check your page `<head>` and check if you set encding, **BUT** also you must populate your page with content encoded in the same `UTF-8`. If (which can often happen) your PHP file is not UTF8 then you will have encoding mismatch and `�` instead.

Comment: Hey. I've tried that. Look at my edited answer to see the HTML I'm using. The response is: `סתם טקסט לבדיקה Array ( [0] => � [1] => � [2] => � [3] => � [4] => � [5] => � [6] => � )`. The issue - unfortunately - remains the same